# Changing font size of h1 inside a div

Tags: html, css

I have an `h1` and a `p` inside a `div`. If i set `font-size: 20px` for the `div`.

Then the paragraph font size become `20px`, but the font size of `h1` get more bigger than `20px`.

Why?

```css
div {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 class="titolo">Prova tag h1</h1>
  <p>Prova paragrafo</p>
  <a href="https:www.google.it">clicca per il link</a>
  <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Because `h1` has a default font-size of 2em which you will have to reset.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the `h1` `font-size` to `initial` value:

```css
div {
  font-size: 50px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: initial;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 class="titolo">Prova tag h1</h1>
  <p>Prova paragrafo</p>
  <a href="https:www.google.it">clicca per il link</a>
  <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png">
</div>
```

References about why:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance

Answer (score 0):

Because the `h1` is getting the size from another unit/value. It is supposed to be bigger than `1em` because `em` is the unit that tells the browser to get the same size of the parent `div`.

You can solve this by these two methods:

**method 1:**

give h1 a style as shown below:

```
h1 { font-size: 1em !important;}
```

This code tells the browser to make `h1` 1 time of parent `div` so if you want to make it 2 times the parent `div` just put `2em` instead.

This also could work:

```
h1 { font-size: inherit !important;}
```

This code tells the browser to make `h1` as exact of the parent `div`

**method 2:**

Just give the style to `h1` directly as shown below:

```
h1 { font-size: 20px !important;}
```